# My java program is not working, I ran the code and the sorting is not right

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the question from my instructor:

1. Load the following items of data into an array interactively from the keyboard.
2. Print out the data in the order in which is was entered.
3. Sort the data in ascending order using the selection sort.
4. Print out the data in sorted order.
5. Sort the data in descending order using the bubble sort.
6. Print out the data in the sorted order.

> These are the data items you’ll use:
>   **Honda, Chevrolet, Ford, Rolls-Royce, Mercedes Benz**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example532 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] list = new String[5];
        System.out.println("Enter data: ");
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            list[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Current data:");
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }
        // call selection sort
        doSelectionSort(list);
        // print out current array
        System.out.println("Sorted data:");
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        } 
        // call bubble sort
        doBubbleSort(list);
        System.out.println("Bubble Sorted data:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }         

    }

    public static String[] doSelectionSort(String[] arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[index]) < 0) 
                    index = j;

            String smaller = arr[index];  
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smaller;
        }
        return arr;
    }    

    public static void doBubbleSort(String[] arr) {
        boolean swapped = true;
        int j = 0;
        String tmp;
        while (swapped) {
            swapped = false;
            j++;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - j; i++) {
                if (arr[i].compareTo(arr[i + 1]) < 0) {
                    tmp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: First of all, what are you trying to achieve by eating braces of `for` loops ? This isn't good coding practice.

Comment: When I run this, it works. What (exact) problems do you run into?

Comment: its not sorting in correct order

Comment: i need the program to sort by the length of the world and not alphabetical order

Comment: You've got two different sorts here. Which isn't working? Please reduce this to a *minimal* example, with hard-coded data, for one specific problem.

Comment: The *main requirement* here (sorting in length rather than alphabetical order) isn't stated anywhere in the question. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort by length, instead of

```
if (arr[j].compareTo(arr[index]) < 0)
```

Use:

```
if (arr[j].length() < arr[index].length())
```

(You need to do this update in multiple places.)

Comment: We're talking two lines of code. One I have done for you so it is essentially copy/paste. The other one is pretty easy too. You can do it! :)

Comment: lol, i got the first one to work but i am still struggling with the second one, maybe cause its 3 am in the morning

Comment: Ok, since you need your sleep (not tested, but should be ok): if (arr[i].length() < arr[i + 1].length()) {

Comment: Thank you so much, i really appreciate you.

Comment: no prob. feel free to mark the answer as "Accepted" :)